# How to exclude traffic with a URL query String from Google Analytics using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, query-string

I tried:

1. Create Variable:

   - Variable type: URL
   - Component type: Query
   - Query Key: "ignoreme", URL Source: Page URL/Default
2. Create Trigger:

   - Trigger type: Page view
   - This trigger fires on: Some page views
   - Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true: ignoreme does not equal "1"

However, when I go to `example.com?ignoreme=1`, the Google Analytics still counts it as a visit and shows me as a visitor. I have published the changes in GTM and deleted my browser cookies.

Comment: This works just fine for me. Did you choose "1" or 1 as the value in your trigger?

Comment: It must have been something like that, it works for me to now. Thank you for checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

Create a pageview trigger:

- Fire on: some pageviews.
- Fire trigger on:
- "Page URL" + "matches RegEx (ignore case)" + "ignoreme=1"

Save trigger.

Edit your Tag for sending "All pages" pageviews to GA.

- Scroll down to Triggering and add Exception.
- Pick the trigger you created as an exception.

Save Tag and preview it before you publish.